# What's the rate limit between requests for Instagram's Private API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the whole list of followers, which means iterating through the pages. However, I don't know whether instagram will ban me with too many requests too quickly. Does anyone know the rate restrictions on instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's private API works like the app do, so you won't have the limits that the official API has, however, you still can't make as many requests, in that case Instagram will know and ban your account.